# FlutterFlow bug in DataTable sorting? Property Panel shows error (Sorted Column Index and Is Ascending) but no error in Action Flow Editor

Tags: sorting, datatable, flutterflow

*[Disclaimer: I'm not a dev and I'm a total noob]*

I've been following plenty of youtube tutorials on how to set up a DataTable widget (here one just as an example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ky3VOgatafs)

The steps are always:

- select DataTable widget
- add action On Change
- update page state:

-> set value: Custom Function

-> arg 1: page state

-> arg 2: sorting index = Data Table "Sorted Column Index" option

-> arg 3: is ascending parameter = Data Table "Is Ascending" option

and all tutorials show this done from Action Flow Editor.

I tried this a few weeks ago and it worked, but already noticed that in the Property Panel (right-hand side of the screen) it showed and error on "**Sorted Column Index**" and "**Is Ascending**". But no bugs reported and I could build the app.

I tried again today, but this time it's showing me a bug that says:

> **App State Update Action**
> *Field "" has an update value that is not properly set in Update App State action for PaginatedDataTable*

This error shows up for the pages I build weeks ago and that were working, and also for a new page that I built today.

Anyone else has stumbled on this? Is this a bug as I think or am I doing anything wrong? If it is a bug, how to bring this to the attention of FlutterFlow team?